# Button - updating graphics - throwing SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, 3d

The PDB structure loads fine, but when I use button to update the image, it will not work. Its making a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Really don't understand why this is like that, the button should just call a method from 3Dmol.js and redraw.
I simplified example since there is multiple buttons to change style and add remove labels.

Original example from here: https://github.com/3dmol/3Dmol.js/blob/master/tests/example.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>3Dmol Example - Changing render options</title>

        <link href="Library/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <!-- Load Online API; defer scripts so they execute after the html has been parsed  -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Library/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script defer src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js" ></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Container for whole page  -->
        <div class='container'>
            <!-- Row for PDB and Plot -->
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="col-md-12" >
                    <div id='viewer3' class='viewer_3Dmoljs' style="width: 600px; height: 600px; float:left;"
                    data-pdb='3SN6' data-backgroundcolor='0xffffff' data-style='{"cartoon":{}}'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row for buttons  -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="gldiv" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <hr style="margin: 0;">

                <input type="button" value="Stick"
                onclick="$3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"].setStyle({},{stick:{}}); $3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"].render();"></input>

                <input type="button" value="Label alpha C's"
                onclick=addLabels($3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"]); $3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"].render();"></input>

                <input type="button" value="Remove labels"
                onclick="$3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"].removeAllLabels(); $3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"].render();"></input>
                    </div>
          </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You know, if you expand the error in the console of your browser... you can find out on which line it happens.

Comment: You can still simplify a whole lot. Which button are you clicking? Can you remove all the non relevant html, apparently there's just a problem with some js with a syntax error

Comment: @Mtihc Button3DmolTest.html:36 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } When i press first one - it gives same error for each button, but on different line (since they are diff lines in code)

Comment: @Axnyff I don't understand what you mean about the html, as for js error i don't get why it happens since i do same as the example they show which works fine

Comment: You're using " in your onclick function. Which means the onclick for the first button for instance is:

`$3Dmol.viewers[` : unvalid javascript. Either mix with ' or espace your " with \"

Comment: @Axnyff So something like this <input type="button" value="Stick" onclick='$3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"].setStyle({},{stick:{}}); $3Dmol.viewers["viewer3"].render();'></input>  Where the outer is ' single quote and inner is double " ???  Can you elaborate how this works??

Comment: When you're setting the value of an attribute in html, it's surrounded either by simple quotes or double quotes. The attribute value ends with the matching simple/double quote. That's you dit by having double quotes in your attributes

Comment: @Axnyff Thanks thats fixed the problem i just suround the outer in single '
On side note would using <button> be better than <input>?? I thought that was the cause of my issue

Comment: It depends. Inside a form, it's better to use an input tag. If you need to have content inside your button (other than text) then you need to use a button tag